# echo "string" > file in Windows PowerShell appends non-printable character to the file

Tags: powershell, cygwin, dos2unix

**In Windows PowerShell:**

```
echo "string" > file.txt
```

**In Cygwin:**

```
$ cat file.txt
:::s t r i n g

$ dos2unix file.txt
dos2unix: Skipping binary file file.txt
```

I want a simple "string" in the file. How do I do it?  I.e., when I say `cat file.txt` I need only "string" as output. I am echoing from Windows PowerShell and that cannot be changed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `echo "string" | out-file -encoding ASCII file.txt` to get a simple ASCII-encoded txt file.

**Comparison of the files produced:**

```
echo "string" | out-file -encoding ASCII file.txt
```

will produce a file with the following contents:

```
73 74 72 69 6E 67 0D 0A (string..)
```

however

```
echo "string" > file.txt
```

will produce a file with the following contents:

```
FF FE 73 00 74 00 72 00 69 00 6E 00 67 00 0D 00 0A 00 (ÿþs.t.r.i.n.g.....)
```

(Byte order mark FF FE indicates the file is UTF-16 (LE). The signature for UTF-16 (LE) = 2 bytes: 0xFF 0xFE followed by 2 byte pairs. xx 00 xx 00 xx 00 for normal 0-127 ASCII chars

Comment: Or you could run `iconv -f utf-16 -t ascii` in Cygwin to convert the file from utf-16 to ASCII.

Answer (score 6):

These two commands are equivalent in that they both use UTF-16 encoding by default:

```
echo "string" > file.txt
echo "string" | out-file file.txt
```

You can add an explicit encoding parameter to the latter form (as indicated by jon Z) to produce plain ASCII:

```
echo "string" | out-file -encoding ASCII file.txt
```

Alternately, you could use `set-content`, which uses ASCII encoding by default:

```
echo "string" | set-content file.txt
```

---

### Corollary 1:

*Want to convert a unicode file to ASCII in one line?*

Just use this:

```
get-content your_unicode_file | set-content your_ascii_file
```

which can be abbreviated to:

```
gc your_unicode_file | sc your_ascii_file
```

---

### Corollary 2:

*Want to get a hex dump so you can really see what is unicode and what is ASCII?*

Use the clean and simple [Get-HexDump](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2010/08/10/displaying-hex-dumps.aspx) function available on PowerShell.com.
With that in place you can examine your generated files with just:

```
Get-HexDump file.txt
```

For anything non-trivial, you can specify how many columns wide you want the output and how many bytes of the file to process with something like this:

```
Get-HexDump file.txt -width 15 -bytes 150
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell creates Unicode UTF-16 files with a Byte Order Mark (BOM).

Dos2unix 6.0 and higher can read UTF-16 files and convert them to UTF-8 (the default Cygwin encoding) and remove the BOM. Versions prior to 6.0 will see UTF-16 files as binary and skip them, as in your example.