# `bower` throws error install the `jquery`

Tags: jquery, node.js, powershell, bower, bower-install

Using the `Windows PowerShell` I am creating a `.bowerrc` file and trying to install the `jquery` using `bower`. i am turn up with error. i am not understand the wrong what i do here..

any one figure out me please?

here is my steps:

```
PS D:\Tutts\Projects\Scratch> echo '{"directory":"lib/scripts/"}'>.bowerrc
PS D:\Tutts\Projects\Scratch> bower install jquery -save

C:\Users\Mohamed.Arif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:55
        throw error;
              ^
Error: Unable to parse D:\Tutts\Projects\Scratch\.bowerrc: Unexpected token ∩┐╜
    at parse (C:\Users\Mohamed.Arif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:48:2
1)
    at json (C:\Users\Mohamed.Arif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:70:12
)
    at rc (C:\Users\Mohamed.Arif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:31:9)
    at Config.load (C:\Users\Mohamed.Arif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-config\lib\Config.js
:14:20)
    at Function.Config.read (C:\Users\Mohamed.Arif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-config\lib\
Config.js:49:19)
    at readCachedConfig (C:\Users\Mohamed.Arif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\config.js:21:51)
    at defaultConfig (C:\Users\Mohamed.Arif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\config.js:11:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mohamed.Arif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\index.js:40:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
PS D:\Tutts\Projects\Scratch>
```

Comment: Read the error message, it tells you everything you need to know: `Error: Unable to parse D:\Tutts\Projects\Scratch\.bowerrc: Unexpected token ∩┐╜` Looks like you've got some characters in your `.bowerrc` file that bower can't parse.

Comment: yes, understand. but from that i am not able to understand what i need to change in file or something else.. can you give a clue?

Comment: Basically when using `echo` (which is an alias of `Write-Output`) it writes a UTF-16 Byte Order Mark at the start of the file. bower obviously isn't happy about this. See this answer for ways around this and to force ASCII output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163922/echo-string-file-in-windows-powershell-appends-non-printable-character-to-th

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `.bowerrc` path to `{"directory":"public/lib"}` this. It works. it seems that, it requires the directory should require to star at `public`..?

Thanks for all.