# Why does ?? appear when I copy one text file to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I copy one text file to another the new file has the two characters: (**??**) at the end which I do not want.

I am using Python3.6.0 on Windows7

This is my script:

```
from sys import argv
script, from_file, to_file = argv

#Open from_file and get the text from it
indata = open(from_file).read()

#Write the from_file text to to_file
open(to_file, 'w').write(indata)
```

I run the following in PowerShell:

```
>echo "This is a test file." > TestSource.txt
>type TestSource.txt
This is a test file.
>python CopyFile.py TestSource.txt TestDestination.txt
>type TestDestination.txt
This is a test file.??
```

**Why do two question marks (??) appear in the file I have created?**

Edit: [This Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163922/echo-string-file-in-windows-powershell-appends-non-printable-character-to-th) was suggested as duplicate. My question is about how Python behaves when I copy one text file to another. Where as this related question is about how Windows PowerShell creates a text file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. i have a suspicion that that last two characters aren't question marks, but something with encoding. can you check what their values are? also try saving the file with ascii encoding , `open(to_file, 'w', encoding='ascii').write(indata)`

Comment: How do I check what their values are? In notepad I see two boxes ਍ഀ.

Comment: Thank you @Nullman.  I tried `open(to_file, 'w', encoding='ascii').write(indata)`. It gives the error: *UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range (128).*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [echo "string" > file in Windows PowerShell appends non-printable character to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163922/echo-string-file-in-windows-powershell-appends-non-printable-character-to-th)

Comment: Apparently PowerShell is creating an UTF-16 file. Try to use `encoding='utf-16'`. Or change your powershell script to write an actual ASCII/utf-8 file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Powershell is creating the file using UTF-16.  You have opened the file in text mode (default) without specifying an encoding, so python calls `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` and uses that encoding (`cp1252` on my US Windows system).

Text mode translates line endings and using the wrong encoding creates problems.  To fix this, use binary mode to get a byte-for-byte copy regardless of encoding.  I also suggest using `with` to ensure the files are closed properly:

```
from sys import argv
script, from_file, to_file = argv

#Open from_file and get the text from it
with open(from_file,'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

#Write the from_file text to to_file
with open(to_file,'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```